Windows Won’t Boot from M.2 SSD After Installing Ubuntu on a Separate SSD
I’ve been successfully booting Windows from my M.2 SSD (WD_BLACK SN770 2TB) for the past year without any issues. However, after installing Ubuntu Server on a separate SSD (WD WDS250G2B0A), I can no longer boot into Windows.
Here’s the current situation:

The M.2 SSD is still recognized as a boot option in the BIOS, but it’s not listed under the M.2 slot in the BIOS M.2. not listed in bios, but as boot option.
I can access the file contents of the M.2 SSD via EZ Boot, so the data appears to be intact  Windows file Contents Inside the M.2.
The boot menu lists both the M.2 SSD and the SSD with Ubuntu as options Boot Menu shows both ssd and M.2 as a boot option.
When I select the M.2 SSD to boot, it either reboots back into the BIOS or directly boots into Ubuntu.

For reference, the BIOS is updated to the latest version (6203 x64).
Hardware:

Motherboard: ASUS ROG STRIX B250-F GAMING
M.2 SSD: WD_BLACK SN770 2TB
Ubuntu SSD: WD WDS250G2B0A

Has anyone experienced a similar issue, or can anyone suggest potential fixes to restore Windows boot functionality from the M.2 SSD?

There are several mentions of 'drives' and zero mentions of 'OS selection'. This suggests you don't understand the UEFI boot process. Unless you did a gross mistake, you can still and always select the Windows bootloader in the Boot menu

As shown in the provided images, the Windows Boot Loader is missing and not available in GRUB either. Based on the description, there’s a common issue at play here: the Windows Boot Loader was likely installed on a different hard drive that previously had Windows on it. When I installed Ubuntu on the new drive, the partition containing the Windows Boot Loader was deleted, which is why I can no longer select it. @ChanganAuto, please take a moment to read the question carefully before responding, as your previous answer was not helpful at all.

The UEFI > Boot menu has nothing to do with GRUB.t

If you’re encountering the same issue, it’s likely that the EFI partition containing the bootloader is missing. The simplest solution, if you want to avoid spending too much time troubleshooting, is to boot into a live Linux environment, back up your important data to an external drive, and then proceed with a clean installation of Windows on the affected hard drive.

This is not the solution - if EFI boot files are missing, there are two solutions, either they can be manually copied to the EFI partition in Ubuntu server from the Windows OS partition’s /Windows/Boot directory, or a Windows install USB can be booted, Shift+F10 to open a terminal once the GUI loads, use DiskPart to mount the EFI partition, list the mount points before exiting via lis vol, then bcdboot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI (where C: is the OS partition and Y: the EFI partition)

(Cont’d…) Once done, you may need to use a Linux utility (I can’t recall the package name) if Windows won’t boot to rebuild the BCD Store. Normally this is done via WinRE or the Windows Install USB [WinPE] by using BootRec, however when dual booting Linux, this can’t be used since it’ll overwrite GRUB, requiring the use of this specific Linux utility to recreate the BCD Store without doing so (while the BCD Store can be manually created from WinPE/WinRE via a different program, it’s an extremely long, complex command)

For someone like me who primarily uses Linux/Mac for work and Windows only for gaming through platforms like Steam, this approach might be more effort than it’s worth—especially if you can easily recover your data or have a backup. That’s why I suggested ‘the simplest solution.’ Reinstalling a few games is quick, and this method worked well for me.

It takes all of a few minutes to resolve this the correct way versus  the 45 - 60min to reinstall Windows and programs (restoring a backup image would take longer than a few minutes). Reinstalling Windows to resolve a boot issue that is easily fixable is extremely inefficient and entirely impractical. Windows keeps a backup of all boot files within Windows\Boot for this very reason (they’re what BcdBoot and BootRec /FixBoot use to recreate boot files). Also, reinstalling Windows overwrites GRUB IIRC, and restoring from a backup will still require updating the BCD Store.
